# Applet not able to access NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress() api

Tags: applet

I have a requirement wherein I want to read the mac address of client m/c using an applet.

But after some googling I found that applets run in a protected sandbox mode and can't have access to `NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()` api. And because of that I am not getting mac address when applet runs in browser where as i get the mac address when applet runs from Eclipse.

Please let me know way so that applet can get access to `NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()` api.

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant the required permission.  See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/wstep2.html).