# Network interface doesn't have any interface addresses

Tags: java, applet

In my applet I retrieve all the network interface with

```
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> systemInterfacesE = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    List<NetworkInterface> systemInterfaces = new ArrayList<NetworkInterface>();

    while (systemInterfacesE.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface systemInterface = systemInterfacesE.nextElement();
        if (!systemInterface.isLoopback() && systemInterface.isUp() && systemInterface.getInterfaceAddresses().size() > 0) {
            systemInterfaces.add(systemInterface);
        }
    }
```

When I run it from Eclipse the list contain my ethernet interface but when I run my applet in HTML the list is empty. It's because there aren't any InterfaceAddresse in systemInterface.

How can I solve this ?

Regards

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525013/applet-not-able-to-access-networkinterface-gethardwareaddress-api